# Integrating Unity 5.6.2 with ARKit to Swift project

Tags: unity-game-engine, swift3, swift4

I am able to integrate the Unity project into my Swift project successfully, but can't able to run the Unity window as I am getting the below error: 
[image]
    ***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key currentUnityController.

I know I am making a mistake somewhere but this already have taken a lot of time. I would appreciate if someone who has tried his hand with this error can help. Below is the code for reference in my AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit

//@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    var unityWindow: UIWindow?
    var currentUnityController: UnityAppController!
    var application: UIApplication?
    var isUnityRunning = false

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    self.application = application
    currentUnityController = UnityAppController()
    currentUnityController.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    UnityGetMainWindow().alpha = 1.0
    // first call to startUnity will do some init stuff, so just call it here and directly stop it again
    startUnity()
    stopUnity()

    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    if isUnityRunning {
        currentUnityController?.applicationWillResignActive(application)
    }
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    if isUnityRunning {
        currentUnityController?.applicationDidEnterBackground(application)
    }
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    if isUnityRunning {
        currentUnityController?.applicationWillEnterForeground(application)
    }
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    if isUnityRunning {
        currentUnityController?.applicationDidBecomeActive(application)
    }
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    if isUnityRunning {
        currentUnityController?.applicationWillTerminate(application)
    }
}

func startUnity() {
    if !isUnityRunning {
        isUnityRunning = true
        currentUnityController!.applicationDidBecomeActive(application!)
    }
}

func stopUnity() {
    if isUnityRunning {
        currentUnityController!.applicationWillResignActive(application!)
        isUnityRunning = false
    }
}
}
```

Attached is the screenshot of the error:

Comment: I know that the below set of line which I added can't able to get the value for key "currentUnityController". But how to resolve this? // ******** ADDED ********
NS_INLINE UnityAppController* GetAppController()
{
    NSObject<UIApplicationDelegate>* delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    UnityAppController* currentUnityController = (UnityAppController *)[delegate valueForKey:@"currentUnityController"];
    return currentUnityController;
}

Comment: No help yet? :P

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved! I somehow able to locate the unityAppController object in ObjC generated header's under derived sources. This wasn't working with the sample app I was creating, I feel the bridging header's are not attached properly.

Comment: I was able to fix it by going to the 'Build Settings' for the target and setting 'Swift Language Version' from 4.0 to 3.2. Thanks Eric!